# Lookup a value from one file to other file and Filter out a pattern matched until the delimeter

Tags: shell, unix

I have two files

refer.txt

```
hello/john,hi/roshan,bye/jill,ok/rashmi
```

main.txt

```
ok/sara/1.0,hello/john/2.1,to/mary/1.2,bye/jill/3.1,cya/trina/2.1
```

so now i need to create a new file output.txt like below

```
hello/john/2.1,bye/jill/3.1
```

Basically refer.txt should do a lookup in main.txt and if the pattern matches it should fetch the whole field from main.txt and place it in output folder.

i have tried the below code:

```
patterns="/soa/admin/raj/test1.txt"
search="/soa/admin/raj/test2.txt"
grep  - -f <(tr ',' '\n' < "${patterns}") "${search}"
```

But didnt work.please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below worked to me using egrep:

```
pattern=`tr ',' '|' < "refer.txt"`
tr ',' '\n' < "main.txt" | egrep "$pattern"
```

**UPDATE:**
To get the output separated by comma just append another tr command as below.

```
pattern=`tr ',' '|' < "refer.txt"`
tr ',' '\n' < "main.txt" | egrep "$pattern" | tr '\n' ','
```

Comment: Thanksyou that worked...i need the o/p file separated by commas

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first cut at a solution.  I find it easiest to create a temporary file, and then use that as the grep pattern:

```
tmpfile=tf$$
tr , '\n' < refer.txt > $tmpfile
tr , '\n' < main.txt | grep -f $tmpfile | tr '\n' ,
rm $tmpfile
```

This still has a few problems, but it's a start.

It would be better if each pattern started with a `^` and ended with a `/`.  That would be easy enough to achieve, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern=`tr ',' '|' < "test1.txt"`
zoo=$(tr ',' '\n' < "test2.txt" | egrep "$pattern" | tr '\n' ,)

echo 'COMPOSITES='$zoo > newfile.txt
sed -i '$s/,$//' newfile.txt
```

this worked